# How to convert an observable-array in an array and return that new array?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, observable

I am trying to convert an observable array in an array and return the new array with the spread operator in the get function.

I tried to convert the observable array manually before subscribing via map operator but there is no solution in sight (it remains an observable of type void)
How do I convert that observable in an array to use the spread operator in `get orders()`where I return an array type?
I need it for a calculation...

```
//in grid.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Order } from '../order/order.model';


@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class OrderGridService{

constructor(private http: HttpClient){}

private _orders: Order[];

getAllOrder(): Observable<Order[]> {
  return this.http.get<Order[]>(this._orderURL + "/" + 
   this.userID + "/" + this.currentUservalueToken);
 };

    get orders(): Order[] {
        return [...this._orders];
    }

}
```

I need to assign to the variable `_orders` the response of the html request I do in the function `getAllOrder()` but there it returns an Observable of `Order[]` instead of an array so I can just return `[...this._orders]`
I hope you understand what I am trying to say..
Thank you for any advice!

Comment: You should return the Array wrapped in an Observable from the Service and then unwrap the Observable in the Component either by calling `subscribe` on it, or by using the `async` pipe in the template.

Comment: So do you want to perform an operation on your array after the "get" is performed and then return that formatted/changed array as an observable. If so i think you can use, pipe and then map operator. Like this this.http.get().pipe(map(array)=>{ do something with an array and return it})

Comment: Then if you want to set your local variable once the get is completed you can chain in a tap operator e.g. this.http.get().pipe(map(()=>{}),tap((array)=>this._orders = array))

Comment: @JustLearning It is the other way. First calling the getAllOrder() function then get is performed. Therefore I need to unwrap the Observable as SiddAjmera mentioned. I will try it

Comment: Related reading [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call). You never really return things from async calls, you can perform actions once complete but you have no way to "return" things

Comment: What your trying to do is already covered quite thoroughly in the Angular tutorials, I'd suggest you read though them, specifically [this one on HTTP](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6) and [this one on observables](https://angular.io/guide/observables)

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like that. But this code is an async. Be careful with that.

```
//in grid.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Order } from '../order/order.model';


@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class OrderGridService{

   constructor(private http: HttpClient){
      // on init of this service get data from an api
      this.getAllOrder().subscribe(data => {
         this._orders = data;
      })
   }

   private _orders: Order[];

   getAllOrder(): Observable<Order[]> {
      return this.http.get<Order[]>(this._orderURL + "/" + 
         this.userID + "/" + this.currentUservalueToken);
   };

   get orders(): Order[] {
      return [...this._orders];
   }
}
```

Comment: Where is the async code? I see you are using obserables but not promises...

Comment: @JamieRees Can you may write what he/you meant?

Comment: @JamieRees, why you say this isn't async?  Observable is an async approach, like a Promises. Look at here please: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/.

_RxJS is a library for reactive programming using Observables, to make it easier to compose asynchronous or callback-based code._

Comment: I meant this is not easy to set data from async method to property. You should subscribe on this of course. And I wrote only example to set these data to the property inside of this service.

Comment: @JamieRees here `this.http.get()` is an async code.

Comment: Pretty clearly asynchronous code. My guess @JamieRees was referring to the javascript's [async & await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) syntax.